# Night rain vs Night train, gemination?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics

[The Wikipedia article on gemination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination#English) claims that gemination of /t/ is the distinguishing factor between the pronunciation of the two phrases *nigh**t t**rain* and *nigh**t** rain*.

In my whole life, I've almost never heard the final /t/ in *night* and the initial /t/ in *train* articulated the same way. The initial /t/ in *train* is affricated due to it being in the /tr/ cluster, while in *night* the /t/ is either a typical English T /t/, unreleased [t̚] or glottalized. They are distinct enough.

I don't think this minimal pair is distinguished by gemination in practical use, as far as I know. How is this pair **really** distinguished? Is there really gemination there?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question that you're asking here - could you rephrase it a little? Or add a sentence with a different wording of the same question?

Comment: An answer could discuss whether *gemination* refers to a phonological or phonetic concept, or whether it depends on context.

Comment: Is this better suited to Linguistics than ELL?  OP seems to be a native speaker of English.

Comment: Interesting topic, but can you clarify what your question is? Is it 'does germination occur in either 'night train or 'night rain'?

Comment: @Mitch I have the minimal pair "night train" and "night rain". Wikipedia claims that the minimal pair is distinguished by gemination. I disagree with them. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: It's still unclear. Gemination is two sounds repeated. Germination doesn't distinguish two _words_. Does my question then make sense? Do you think gemination doesn't occur in either string? It's hard to tell exactly what you are disagreeing with.

Comment: I would tend to pronounce "night train" as "nigh train", though there would be a hint of a "t'" appended to "nigh".  And there would be a definite "tr" sound that would be absent in "night rain".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In my whole life, I've almost never heard the final /t/ in night and the initial /t/ in train articulated the same way.

Short answer: dialectal variation (and I think it's a poor choice for an example of gemination)

The Wikipedia article you cite qualifies this example as a minimal pair "for most accents" (which I doubt, but that's Wikipedia for you).  I also notice that, in that section, it's the only example without an IPA transcription (further raising my suspicion).

You'd need a [phonologist](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) and a fluoroscope to distinguish all the variation in "night train"

/ˈnaɪt treɪn/ /ˈnaɪt̚ treɪn/ /ˈnaɪʔ ʧreɪn/ /ˈnaɪt̚ t͡ʃreɪn/ /ˈnaɪʔ t͡ʃreɪn/ /ˈnaɪt͡ʃreɪn/

and "night rain" among English speakers.

/ˈnaɪt reɪn/ /ˈnaɪt̚ʔ reɪn/ /ˈnaɪʔ reɪn/ /ˈnaɪɾ reɪn/

Some of these might still make a minimal contrast pair, but with [t-glottalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-glottalization), [pre-glottalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottalization#English), an [unreleased stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_audible_release#English), or even a [flap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flapping) potentially replacing one half of the twin pair, it would not necessarily be gemination.

You're not the first person to question that particular example. (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Gemination#.22night_train.22_versus_.22night_rain.22 
)

Comment: I tried to strip this example off the Wikipedia because of this sort of logic, but another person reverted it.